# How to download images on wikipedia using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am starting to use BeautifulSoup and am currently trying to download images from Wikipedia.

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
images = soup.find_all("img", attrs = {"alt": "GenericAttribute"})
for image in images:
    image_src = image["src"]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_src)
```

No error messages appear, however, I cannot seem to download the images correctly. I believe the issue is in the soup variable or the images variable, but I do not know what to change them to to make them functional in relation to Wikipedia. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531668/4539709

Comment: Here is also an answer for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474932/how-to-get-all-image-urls-with-urllib-request-urlopen-from-multiple-urls